# Django context returned by get_object

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

```
class ListDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'aaaa'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return List.objects.get(unique_list_id=self.kwargs['unique_list_id'])
```

In template I have two equal contexts:

```
{{ object.list_name }}
{{ aaaa.list_name }}
```

How to override get_object() to return only context specified by `context_object_name = 'aaaa'`?
Why I have 2 contexts?

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* determined by the [**`get_object`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object), but determined by the implementation of the [**`get_context_data`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) of the [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview). Indeed, for views that inherit from the [**`SingleObjectMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin), [it is implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/views/generic/detail.py#L91):

> ```
> def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
>     """Insert the single object into the context dict."""
>     context = {}
>     if self.object:
>         context['object'] = self.object
>         context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(self.object)
>         if context_object_name:
>             context[context_object_name] = self.object
>     context.update(kwargs)
>     return super().get_context_data(**context)
> ```

So it will always set the object to the `self.object` (if that object exists), and if there is a `context_object_name`, to that name as well.

You can slightly update that, by removing it from the dictionary, like:

```
class ListDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'aaaa'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context.pop('object', None)
        return context

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return List.objects.get(unique_list_id=self.kwargs['unique_list_id'])
```

That being said, I don't see any benefit to remove it. It refers to the same object. The query is *not* done twice: these are two names in the context that refer to the object. It makes the context more *uniform*, such that a base template can work on the `object` value as well.

Note that even if you remove this, you can still access the object through:

```
{{ view.object.list_name }}
```

Since the basic implementation of `get_context_name` will add the `view` variable to the context that refers to the instance constructed of the view.